# Fetch data from API using React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data from the url below, but when I launch the code it returns the error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'res.data.hints')`, and consequentially nothing happens, I've followed various tutorials and they seem to come up with this code.

**States**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateSearch();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }
```

**Function**

```
 updateSearch = () => {
        const url = `https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/parser?ingr=b&app_id=000&app_key=00000&page=20`;
        fetch(url)
           .then((res) => res.json())
           .then((res) => {
             this.setState({
               data: res.data.hints
             });
           })
           .catch(error => {
            console.log("error : "+ error)
          });
      };
```

**Flatlist**

```
     <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <View>
                  <Text>{item.label}</Text>
                  <Text>{item.brand}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </ListItem>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.foodId}
        />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.setState({
           data: res.hints
         });
```

Try this

Comment: It now shows only the lines of the separator of the Flatlist, no labels appear in the Flatlist and also it returns the Warning: ` Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

Comment: To remove the warning you will have to provide the a key props to the parent component where you are mapping the fetched data

Comment: I'm generally new to programming, how can I do that?

Comment: <ListItem key={item.food.foodId}>, and also to render the items on screen you will have to use the following code :
    <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem key={item.food.foodId}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <View>
                  <Text>{item.food.label}</Text>
                  <Text>{item.food.brand}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </ListItem>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.food.foodId}
        />